# hidden component in material-ui, how to prevent rendering?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I've been using nextJS and material-ui with great success so far.
However I've been hitting a conceptual issue lately :
Whenever the app renders on the server, I don't want it to reflow once it arrives on the client.
Since I'm rendering layout differently between a desktop and a mobile device, I've been separating components using the `<Hidden implementation='css'/>` component. I'm using `implementation=css` because I can't rely on the window width since it will not be available on the server.
My main problem today, is that both the desktop and the mobile version are rendered, even if the correct one is displayed on screen, it results in unnecessary logic execution (especially api calls).
I think I did something wrong, but don't know how to fix it.
The 'ideal' way would be a component like `<Hidden/>` but instead of just hidding an already rendered component, it will just not render it at all... and I can't use `window.innerWidth` of course since I care about SSR...

If anyone has an idea, I would be grateful.

Comment: Maybe you could spoof on the agent? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! actually material UI docs recommends using user-agent or client-hints, as stated here https://material-ui.com/api/hidden/. But support for client-hints is not wide enough yet

Comment: Also, to be more precise, detecting the device type on server side is nice, but not enough, the mobile layout should be displayed on a laptop if the viewport width is small enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, I finally found not a perfect, but an optimal solution for my case:
when the rendering is done server side, I'm using material-ui `<Hidden implementation='css'/>` (the same can be achieve with a media-query react component), so that the component renders both the desktop and the mobile version, and then immediatly hide the right one (no flickr on screen).
Then when the rendering is done client side, I'm calculating `window.innerWidth` so that the component doesn't recalculate the mobile and the desktop version for each state change.
Here is my code :

```
<Fragment>
  <Display format="mobile" css>
    {process.browser
      ? this.state.width < 960 ? mobile() : null
      : mobile()}
  </Display>
  <Display format="tablet-desktop" css>
    {process.browser
      ? this.state.width >= 960 ? tablet_desktop() : null
      : tablet_desktop()}
  </Display>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: How come you decided to use <Hidden> instead of just using the material UI theme breakpoints or a basic style yourself?